# bucket data in R Data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, binning

I have a code in python that creates bucket dataframe from a simple dataframe. I want to replicate in R. Till now I understand that I can use transform function but I am unable to do it. can anyone help me in this?

This is dataframe

[image]

Here is the bucketing code in python

[image]

Comment: As my reputation is low I am not able to add images so it is embedding links to the images in question

Comment: Even R has `cut` function which might be helpful.  Read `?cut`

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with below lines of code

```
bins = seq(0,max(df_s$wordCount)+input$bins,by = 5)
df_s <-transform(df_s,group = cut(df_s$wordCount,bins))
df <- aggregate(df_s$Freq, by=list(Category=df_s$group), FUN=sum)
```

@Ronak, thanks for your advice.